# computing length of a curve given as set of points

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Given a set of points $(x_i,y_i)$ from a simple curve. How can the length of the curve be computed approximately??

I understand these points can be connected by line segments and the sum of the lengths of  is an approximation but are there any other better methods??

thanks

Comment: Cubic splines when you want smoothness, but it depends on what you want to achieve. Bezier curves are also quite common.

Comment: It is not really trivial to compute the arc length of a cubic spline, so you would use it to refine your set of sampling points and then compute again the sum of the segment lengths.

Comment: @LutzL yes thats the problem with higher order polynomials. can we use interpolation for refining the samples or any techniques from machine learning?

Comment: With polynomial interpolation, and if I remember correctly, also approximation, you always have to care for the Runge effect.  -- To upgrade from the polygon you might want to use a differentiable curve. The minimum for that is to ascribe tangents to every sample point and demand that the change in the tangent from point to point is minimal. If you put this in equations, you will again end up with the equations for a cubic spline. This is faster than any machine learning method. What is the characteristic of the sample points, sparse or dense (and noisy)?